# PHP Warning: Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, bash, soap

Hi, I have a problem with this error: PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I am running vps on media temple.  I got some instructions from their knowledge base and I followed them exactly as described.  However to see if SOAP properly installed i went to the command line and ran "pear list" and this is what I get.

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'soap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.11  stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
[root@w8ld-gg7p ~]# rep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini
-bash: rep: command not found
[root@w8ld-gg7p ~]#
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? First off it doesn't load SOAP in the installed packages list.  Second I get that SOAP loaded in unkown error.

I'm a newbie so any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you are loading the 'soap' module multiple times
instead of `rep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini`, you should use `grep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini` to search the modules loaded

If your ini is in different location, you need to find where is it.

1. If you got PHP Warning from webpage, you can create a file with this
   as the content:

   ```
   <?php
   phpinfo();
   ?> in your browser, search for "Loaded Configuration File" and "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"
   ```
2. If you got PHP Warning when running PHP on the shell, run this on
   shell:

   ```
   php -r "phpinfo();" | awk '/^Loaded|^Scan/ {print $NF}'
   ```

depends on your installation, besides php.ini you may have ini files in php.d

for my redhat server:

> ; Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
>
> ; found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response.  So what I did was I went to the command line in my terminal and I typed in: grep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini  and this is what I got: grep: /usr/local/lib/php.ini: No such file or directory

Comment: @user2690257 in your question, you were searching /usr/local/lib/php.ini, thought that was your php.ini location. I have updated my reply, please try it to get php.ini and any other additional ini loaded. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Comment the extension=soap in one of the files:

e.g = in your Xampp (php.ini)

```
;extension=soap
```

Comment: i comment that line and worked for me thanks. but if we have more project how can we manage if we want to develop more than 1 project simultaneously. how can we mange these conflicts

Answer (score 2):

Go to: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/

Then:

```
ls | grep soap
```

Two files will be listed:

- 20-soap.ini
- 40-soap.ini

Comment the extension=soap.so in one of the files:

```
;extension=soap.so
```

Done.

If you're using Docker, comment the follow line in your /workspace/Dockerfle:

```
echo "extension=soap.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/40-soap.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for mbstring module.    As we have two php.ini file one in apache2 and the other in cli  You should uncomment (and hence load) in only one php.ini file the line 
    ;extension=php_soap.dll(so)
This should suppress the warning.